# Haskell example programs

Tags: haskell

So I've been trying to learn Haskell for a week now but I think it's time to do some small projects (like, a small guessing game or such). Can you all direct me into some project's I can take a look at and try and recreate.

Comment: I had used https://wiki.haskell.org/H-99:_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems . These are the best set of algo programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A place that I like for practicing problems is Exercism
Apart from the unit testing validation, volunteers check your code and give you human feedback.

https://exercism.org/tracks/haskell